# Can I incorporate my existing Bot build to run in Bot Composer

Tags: botframework, bots

I have an existing Bot build on bot framework sdk but now I need to shift that into Bot Framework composer so that in future all the developments can happen over composer. Can anyone help me with steps to migrate existing bot into composer.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no documented steps for migrating a bot to Composer. My recommendation is to familiarize yourself with the Composer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/introduction) and practice using it until you're confident enough to rebuild your bot's functionality in Composer.

Composer uses [declarative dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-adaptive-dialog-declarative) which in turn use [adaptive dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-adaptive-dialog-introduction). In the unlikely scenario that your bot already uses either of those things, the transition will be easier. In the more likely scenario that your bot isn't already using adaptive dialogs, the logic of your bot will need to be rebuilt in an entirely new format and so there's no way to simplify that process into easy steps.